# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in fix-keyboard-input patch of st

Tags: c, archlinux, x-st

I've patched suckless's st recently and noticed when I install it via a PKGBUILD file with this command `makepkg -sri` rather than just `sudo make install` it breaks on startup and gives the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So I did a `git bisect` and found out [this patch](https://st.suckless.org/patches/fix_keyboard_input) was causing the issue. I should probably email the author of the patch, although because it has not been updated since 2018 I doubt this will get me any where.

Any Ideas?

- OS: Archlinux
- Github: https://github.com/utilyre/st (on commit [520a554f7ce49f70e07f4eac5a89b454c445f6d4](https://github.com/utilyre/st/commit/520a554f7ce49f70e07f4eac5a89b454c445f6d4) )
- AUR: `utilyre-st-git`

This is the PKGBUILD file I used for building it:

```bash
pkgname="utilyre-st-git"
_reponame="st"
pkgver="0.8.6"
pkgrel="1"
pkgdesc="A simple virtual terminal emulator for X"
arch=("i686" "x86_64" "armv7h")
url="https://github.com/utilyre/st"
license=("MIT")
depends=("libxft-bgra")
makedepends=("ncurses" "libxext" "git")
provides=("st")
conflicts=("st" "st-git")
source=("git+$url.git")
sha256sums=("SKIP")

build() {
    cd "$_reponame"
    make X11INC="/usr/include/X11" X11LIB="/usr/lib/X11"
}

package() {
    cd "$_reponame"
    make PREFIX="/usr" DESTDIR="$pkgdir" install
    install -Dm644 "LICENSE" "$pkgdir/usr/share/licenses/$pkgname/LICENSE"
    install -Dm644 "README.md" "$pkgdir/usr/share/doc/$pkgname/README.md"
}
```

Comment: What about the segfault itself and try to fix it ?

Comment: Just fork the repo I guess. Or if the segmentation fault is present in the main branch of suckless's st, you can probably submit a pull request to get it fixed.

Comment: Yeah that's the issue. Since I don't know much c, I only patched it and didn't actually modify the source code

Comment: No the master branch of suckless is fine. I've done the patch that I mentioned in the question above and that is the source of the issue. I cannot undo the patch though because I need it for some tui applications that I use (e.g. neovim)